# How to disable SSL hostname verification with Gatling and SSL two way

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, gatling, sni

I'm trying to create a Gatling test with SSL two way but I'm not able to disable hostname verification. I'm using Gatling 2.3. Here's my Gatling configuration :

```
ssl {
  keyStore {
    type = "JKS"
    file = "keystore.jks"
    password = "changeit"
    #algorithm = ""
  }
  trustStore {
    type = "JKS"
    file = "truststore.jks"
    password = "changeit"
    #algorithm = ""
  }
}
ahc {
  acceptAnyCertificate = true
  ....
}
```

I have also added this system properties at the beginning of my App

```
System.setProperty("jdk.tls.allowUnsafeServerCertChange", "true")
System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", "true")
```

I can see that my keystore and trutstore are correctly used but I keep having this issue :

```
java.security.cert.CertificateException: No subject alternative DNS name matching <my_dns> found.
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.matchDNS(HostnameChecker.java:204)
at sun.security.util.HostnameChecker.match(HostnameChecker.java:95)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:455)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkIdentity(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:436)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:252)
at sun.security.ssl.X509TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(X509TrustManagerImpl.java:136)
at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1493)
... 28 common frames omitted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If someone is still looking for a solution: this feature has been implemented in v3.0 of Gatling.

The relevant configuration parameters are:

```
ahc {
    enableSni = true                                    # When set to true, enable Server Name indication (SNI)
    enableHostnameVerification = false                  # When set to true, enable hostname verification: SSLEngine.setHttpsEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [Gatling SSL documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/2.3/http/http_ssl/) you could try disabling SNI (`-Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false`). However, if you really need SNI (SSL virtual hosting) you don't want to do that, and you need to code your own [HostNameVerifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#HostnameVerifier) although I have no idea how you can include that in Gatling.

Comment: my bad, I haven't said it in my question but I added to this option `Djsse.enableSNIExtension=false`. I think too, I need to create my own HostNameVerifier but yep i don't know how to inject it.

Comment: and what was the result ?

Comment: I understood, but did you get the very same Exception or another one ? If Gatling is overriding properties, you can try -Djavax.net.debug=all to get more log and maybe we can find out a solution.

Comment: Thx for your help. I got the same error and by activating `javax.net.debug=all` I could not find more explanation. I finally stop to try to make it work.