# AWS Lamdba slow responses

Tags: python, java, amazon-web-services, performance, aws-lambda

Currently, I'm doing load testing using Gatling and I have one issue with my lambdas. I have two lambdas one is written in Java 8 and one is written in Python. I'm using Gatling for my load testing and I have a test where I'm doing one request with 120 concurrent users then I'm ramping them from 120 to 400 users in 1 minute, and then Gatling is doing requests with 400 constants users per second for 2 minutes.
There is a weird behavior in these lambdas because the responses are very high. In the lambdas there is no logic, they are just returning a String.
Here are some screenshots of Gatling reports:
[Java Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCx9M.png)
[Python Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SuHU0.png)
I can add that I did some tests when Lambda is warm-up and there is the same behaviour as well.
I'm using API Gateway to run my lambdas.

Do you have any idea why there is such a big response time? Sometimes I'm receiving an HTTP error that says:

```
 i.n.h.s.SslHandshakeTimeoutException: handshake timed out after 10000ms
```

Here is also my Gatling simulation code:

```
public class OneEndpointSimulation extends Simulation {

HttpProtocolBuilder httpProtocol = http
        .baseUrl("url") // Here is the root for all relative URLs
        .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/json,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8") // Here are the common headers
        .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
        .acceptLanguageHeader("en-US,en;q=0.5")
        .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.8; rv:16.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/16.0");

ScenarioBuilder scn = scenario("Scenario 1 Workload 2")
        .exec(http("Get all activities")
                .get("/dev")).pause(1);

{
    setUp(scn.injectOpen(
                    atOnceUsers(120),
                    rampUsersPerSec(120).to(400).during(60),
                    constantUsersPerSec(400).during(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
            ).protocols(httpProtocol)
    );
}
}
```

Comment: Is the "url" a third party - i.e. something you don't control?

Comment: Look at the actual Lambda metrics in CloudWatch.

Comment: @stdunbar I didn't wanted to paste actual URL. The URL is my API Gateway Rest API URL.

Comment: @jarmod I checked them and there is nothing there. Also all of the requests returned 200 in lambda.

Comment: You won't see anything in CloudWatch because it only monitors what happens AFTER the public endpoint in charge of connections and TLS termination, so you can't see connection and TLS errors in there.

Comment: I was proposing to review the CW Lambda metrics simply as an additional diagnostic. You should be able to infer, for example, what percentage of requests actually resulted in invoked Lambdas, what their average runtime was etc. Hopefully that confirms the problem is not the Lambdas but, perhaps API Gateway. Then I would [troubleshoot API Gateway logs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-cloudwatch-logs/).

Comment: Also, you haven't given any indication of what your Lambda config looks like, especially concurrency limits (related info [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-concurrency-limit-increase)).

Comment: @jarmod I checked it and all lambdas where triggered, also the mean runtime was ~30ms. Lambda config: 512mb and 1000 concurrency limit. Could it be that Gatling is breaking something?

Comment: Your Gatling clients are all hitting the same API Gateway endpoint URL, yes? Does API Gateway logging show anything related to these failures? Also, out of interest, wonder if you can test after enabling/disabling SNI in Gatling (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755456/how-to-disable-ssl-hostname-verification-with-gatling-and-ssl-two-way)).

Comment: Yes, I disabled SSL and SNI in Gatling and it seems that it is working now fine. Thank you!

Comment: Can you add more detail about the Lambda setup and their response times under normal use? Adding X-Ray tracing with sub-segments would be a good way to identify when time is being spent.